# multicolour bar chat in android

Tags: android, bar-chart, charts4j

I am working on an android application.In my app i have to show a multicolour bar chart like the below.
[image: multicolor bar chart]

I searched a lot in net but get different suggestions about libraries. At last I find the only solution is [chart4j](https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/) . In this page their graph chart also showing multiple colour.But there I get only java code but I failed make it as a android application.

I got one android sample application using charts4j from [here](http://subinsugunan.blogspot.in/2012/01/charts4j-android-example.html).But its giving exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main


 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.googlecode.charts4j.Data
```

So please try to  help me to find solution to show multicolour graph chart.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the exception by creating a folder named libs rather than lib.
The reason for using libs is

> Android's current build tools (Eclipse and command-line) expect that JARs are in a libs/  directory. It will automatically add those JARs to your compile-time build path. More importantly, it will put the contents of the JARs into your APK file, so they will be part of your run-time build path.
>
> Using lib/ and mucking with your build path manually will solve the compile-time problem, but then your JAR contents are not in your APK and therefore will not be available to you at runtime.